# Merging many MP3 files via command line on Ubuntu

Tags: software-recommendation, mp3

I am looking for a program that can merge many MP3 files via command line on Ubuntu (e.g., as soon I have a folder containing many MP3 files and I want to merge them into a single MP3 file).

- `mp3wrap` may only merge up to 255 files (http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/faq.html#q6 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171204223915/http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/faq.html)))
- `sox` may only merge up to 348  files (https://superuser.com/a/571468/116475 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20171204224000/https://superuser.com/questions/571463/how-do-i-append-a-bunch-of-wav-files-while-retaining-not-zero-padded-numeric))). I'm not sure if the 348 but whatever the exact number is, there seems to be a low limit in the hundreds of thousands.

Any license or price is fine.

Answer (score 0):

[mp3cat](https://tomclegg.ca/mp3cat) seems to have no limitations as you can add a directory as the input. From the link:

> Summary
>
> `mp3cat` reads and writes MP3 files.

```
$ mp3cat [options] - - < infile.mp3 > outfile.mp3
$ mp3cat [options] - outdir < infile.mp3
$ mp3cat [options] indir - > outfile.mp3
$ mp3cat [options] indir outdir
```

You would need the 3rd option.

> Installation

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/src
cd /usr/local/src
git clone https://github.com/tomclegg/mp3cat
cd mp3cat
make install
```

The installation dir is not what I would use but the command was written for FreeBSD. I would install in /opt/ if it was me.